# Align images to the right of text in container

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

I am trying to align two icons (the facebook and google+ icons) of my website found [here](http://introspect-pictures.co.uk/index.php). These little round icons can be seen just below the navigation bar at the top. The navigation bar is part of a class 'container_header', defined in the file 'stylesheet.css'.

The webpage' 'index.php' contains this code where the icons should be contained within the top container:

```
<div class ="container_header">
<div class="header_img"><a href="index.php" class="head"><img border="0" src="images/introspect-pictures_logo_header.png" alt="Home" width="185" height="28"></a></div>
<div class="header">
<a href="index.php" class="body">HOME</a>..........<a href="about.php" class="body">ABOUT</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

<div id="social">
<a href="https://www.facebook.com" target="_blank"><img border="0" src="images/ic_fb.png" alt="Facebook"></a>
<a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank"><img border="0" src="images/ic_gp.png" alt="Google+"></a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

And within 'stylesheet.css' the icons (within the 'social' class) have their properties defined as such (with '#'s):

```
#social {
float: right;
width: 60px;
text-align: right;
}

#social a {
float: right;
margin: 20px 0 0 5px;
}

#social a img {
width: 24px;
height: 24px;
border: 0;
}
```

The 'container_header' class properties are defined in the same file as:

```
.container_header{
width:800px;
margin:0 auto 0 auto;
padding:10px;
border:0px solid #000000;
border-radius: 5px;
color: #666666;
}
```

Could anyone please help me align them next to the navigation bar (next to 'About') so they are also contained within the container `width (800px)`.

Many thanks,

Pete

Comment: Please add some code here, not outside the site.

Comment: I have added some code now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, get rid of the `width` of `.header`. This is the reason why your social icon is not seating beside your menu item. Then remove `margin-top` from `#social a`.

**EDIT:** Using `width:100%;` for `.header` will also works.

Hope it'll helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
.header {
background: #000000;
width: 60%;
float:right;
font-size: 100%;
color: #666666;
font-family: ProximaNovaLight, Proxima Nova Light;
text-align: center;
}
```

Then put social div before the a hrefs